# Reducing javascript repetition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tabbed menu system and on tab click loads a specific page into the tabs relevant div.

Currently I have a series of the following functions. A set for each tab and this makes for some pretty ugly code. Is there anything I can do to simplify and reduce the repetition?

Each "TAB" instance is the name of the tab that has been clicked. The {% url ... %} section is a Django dynamic URL.

I was thinking that if the tab name and url were put into an array of sorts it would at least enable for all the functions to be created en masse. But is there away of simplifying it further?

Thank you for any help.

```
    function loadTABlog() {
        $("#TABlog").load("{% url list_TABlog person.id %}", function(response, status, xhr) {
            if (status == "error") {
                var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                $("#TABlog").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    };
    $("#loadTABlog").click(function() {
        $("#TABlog").empty().html('<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}loading.gif" class="ajaxloader" />');
        loadTABlog();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d try to make it data-driven. Something along the lines of

```
var tabs = [
    {activator: "#loadTabLog",
     element: "#tabLog",
     url: "{% url list_tab_log 9000 %}"},
    ...
];
```

And iterate through it, assigning handlers:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; ++i) {
    var t = tabs[i];
    $(t.activator).click(function() {
        $(t.element).empty().html("<img>");
        ...
        $(t.element).load(t.url.replace("9000", actual_user_id), ...);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi ayanami. That's an interesting idea. I have tried to implement what you suggested, but it only seems to make one of the tabs work - the last one. If I remove the last tabs activator section it then works but for the new last tab.

Comment: And if I put an alert in the for loop for t.url it always shows the same url no matter which tab is clicked.

Comment: @user973347 without seeing the code, or preferably jsfiddle, I can’t help you at all ._.

Comment: $.each(tabs, function() {
            console.log(this.activator + ' ' + this.element);
            $(this.element).empty().html('<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}loading.gif" class="ajaxloader" />');
            $(this.element).load(this.url, function(response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                    $($(this).attr('href')).html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
                return false;
            });
        });

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8tEA4/

This fixes it. I understand now that because of it being a late binding language the "i" in the loop only existed at the end of the loop for use. Hence why it was always the last tab.

Thanks again for your help ayanami.

Comment: @user973347 right, I was about to suggest using a closure. Don’t mention it :)